# How do I upload single chunk payload with AWSSDK.S3?

Tags: aws-sdk, aws-sdk-net

I'm writing a .NET application which is sending files to a server using AWSSDK.S3 library.

The server that I'm sending files to is an internal solution implementing a subset of Amazon S3 functionality, and currently not supporting chunked upload.

How do I enable single chunk upload?

Answer (score 0):

To change the current behavior I had to set

```
putRequest.UseChunkEncoding = false;
```

in Amazon.S3.Transfer.Internal.SimpleUploadCommand.ConstructRequest()

It seems that library clients currently have no way to change it.

Link for the issue: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/1057